# Storing static object reference into a non-static instance variable

Tags: c#, reference, static

My goal is to keep static Bitmaps in child classes and use logic in base class with minimal amount of code in child classes.

At the moment I've got 2 classes: `LEDa`, `LEDb`, that derive from `LED`. Each of the child classes needs it's own set of `static` objects (huge bitmaps) to prevent high ram usage. I'm passing child bitmaps to base methods as arguments, but I want to reduce that "linking" code to minimum.

I've come to a *possible* solution, however it seems quite hacky so i decided to ask for a second opinion. I am thinking of passing child's static bitmap references into an instance variable of a base class.

```
class LED{
   Bitmap bmp;
   Bitmap[] StateBMP;
   int state;
   public LED(Bitmap bmp){
      this.bmp = bmp;
      createStateBMPs();
   }
}
class LEDa : LED{ //code is identical in LEDb
   static Bitmap bmp = .......;
   static Bitmap[] StateBMP;
   public LEDa():base(bmp){   
   }
}
```

If I got it correctly, initializing multiple instances of `LEDa` and `LEDb`  would only load 2 bitmaps into memory and all of bitmaps in `LED` would just  be references linking to 1 of the 2 bitmaps.

I am wondering if there is better way to deal with this problem.

Comment: `needs it's own set of static objects (huge bitmaps) to prevent high ram usage`... why's that? Are you using loads of LEDa/b objects?

Comment: I am using a whole bunch of each of child classes - about 200 on screen with similar bitmap processing. As for constructor yeah. I left a mistake in code, I corrected it now.

Comment: How is `static Bitmap[] StateBMP` setted? through constructor?

Comment: LED class has a couple of methods to clone bmp and apply masks to it. It is initialized in a contructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent quite a few hours trying different things to achieve the goal, and static bmp passed to base class instance object DOES work. My only concern is having an unecessary duplicate object reference in each instance of `LED`.

Following Stefan's answer I have found an approach (that would not lead to the same class objects having multiple identical references). Basically, a static Bitmap in child classes, which can be accessed by base class with overridden properties:

```
class LED{

   /*
    I used NULL instead of Global.DefaultBitmap, which worked just fine
    if you don't leave lose ends, but these classes are actually
    Controls and the UserControl test container kept giving me errors
    when I scrolled through base control, so I decided to add a static
    10x10 image/icon to all base controls to have that instead of errors.
   */
   public virtual Bitmap bmp {get {return Global.DefaultBitmap;} set{}}

   public LED(){}
}
class LEDa : LED{ //code is identical in LEDb
   static Bitmap _bmp;
   public override Bitmap bmp{get{return _bmp;}set{_bmp=value}}

   public LEDa(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you try to achieve is a **Singleton**, there are many variations about this, but most easy solution can look like this.

```
public class LED{
   Bitmap bmp;
   public LED(Bitmap bmp){
      this.bmp = bmp;
   }
}

public static class LEDSingleton
{
    private static Dictionary<string,LED> LEDs = new Dictionary<string, LED>();

    public static LED Instance(string name, Bitmap bmp)
    {
        if (!LEDs.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            LEDs.Add(name, new LED(bmp));
        }

        return LEDs[name];
    }
}
```

And you use it like this

```
var LEDa1 = LEDSingleton.Instance("LEDa", new Bitmap(..));
var LEDb = LEDSingleton.Instance("LEDb", new Bitmap(..));
var LEDa2 = LEDSingleton.Instance("LEDa", new Bitmap(..)); // same instance as LEDa1
```

**Note:**

1. Instead of `string` name can be an `enum` or something else.
2. Any IoC (Inversion of Control) container can work very well in this case because you can configure the class to be in *singleton scope* and every time you get and instance of that type, will be the same.

Comment: I don't think it is suitable here. I failed to show that in my code but, each of the child classes have multiple bitmaps created from 1st one and they may chance states independently.

Comment: @Zero here i take an instance of `LED` but also can be a instance of `Bitmap` works in both ways.

Comment: @Zero Why you made `LEDa` and `LEDb`? They have different logic from `LED` or they just represent same `LEDa` everywhere and same `LEDb` everywhere?

Comment: The only difference in code between LEDa and LEDb is the image which is used. However, in project I use these 2 classes in they have completely different sets of configurations. For instance: LEDa only has ON and OFF states, while LEDb has a different image and blinks when on.